# Php Calendar starting with current week instead of Day 1

Tags: php, calendar

Is there a way to create a calendar in PHP that starts with the current week (sunday) and goes for X weeks? Here is a design for reference, I like that the month is in the first column of the table. Instead of having lines speperating each month, I thought it may be easier to use different color shading for each cell that belongs to a particular month.

Here is some code that lays the groundwork by getting the current week and an array for 6 weeks out.

```
function getDatesFromRange($start,$end){
    $dates = array($start);
    while(end($dates) < $end){
        $dates[] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(end($dates).' +1 day'));
    }
    return $dates;
}

$current_date = '2018-01-28';
// check if current is sunday
$dayw = date('w',strtotime($current_date));
$start_date = $current_date;
if($dayw != 0){
    $prev_sunday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last sunday '.$current_date));
    $start_date = $prev_sunday;
}
$end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+6 weeks '.$start_date));
$date_ranges = getDatesFromRange($start_date,$end_date);
unset($date_ranges[41]);
```

[image]

Comment: "Is there a way?" Yes. You have the array ready (though I think you should `unset` index 42 instead of 41), so the rest is mostly about generating e.g. a `<table>`. What have you tried? Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: unsetting that index allows the calendar to end of sat (could also use +6 weeks 6 days), I haven't coded too much at this point because I didn't want to reinvent the wheel if there was already something like this out there..